# How to run watch in Laravel 9?

Tags: laravel

When I use `npm run watch` show me error `missing script: watch` so I add watch in `package.json` and when I use npm run watch show me this error.

```
`> vite build --watch
Failed at the @ watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-22T20_21_40_496Z-debug.log
```

I don't know how to resolve this problem. I will gratefull if someone help me. This is my `package.json`

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "watch": "vite build --watch"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.2",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: If you read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#main-content), the latest Laravel 9.x comes with `vite`, you just have to run `npm run dev`, and it will automatically watch

Comment: @matiaslauriti When I `npm run dev` show me error

Comment: What is the error, if you don't share stuff, we can't help...

Comment: @matiaslauriti That's error `failed to load config from C:\laragon\www\laravel-od-podstaw\vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
Error: Cannot find module 'node:path'
Require stack:
`

Comment: Either edit the question or delete and create a new one, this is a new error. Did you run `npm install`? Do you have the latest LTS or latest NodeJS version? Do you have a normal `vite.config.js` or did you modified it? You need to add more info...

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to update Node.js to the latest version
You can visit : https://nodejs.org/en/download/ to download the latest version and it should work